# I'm struggling with finding variance of Ito integral.

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, variance

Find $D \int_{0}^{t}W^{2}_{s}dW_{s}$ My solution is next:
variance = $E(\int_{0}^{t}W^{2}_{s}dW_{s})^{2} - (E\int_{0}^{t}W^{2}_{s}dW_{s})^{2}$
Which is equal to (using Ito's isometry principle) = $\int_{0}^{t}EW_{s}^{4}dW_{s} - (\int_{0}^{t}EW_{s}^{2}dW_{s})^{2}$

And that is easily calculable. But i wonder if all steps are correct

Comment: What does "D" means in $D \int_{0}^{t}W^{2}_{s}dW_{s}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_0^t X_s \, dW_s \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$$
for any stochastic process in $\mathcal{L}^2$ (this comes comes from the fact that the previous r.v. is a countable sum of normal distributions).

$$\mu=\mathbb{E}[\int_0^t W_s^2 \, dW_s]=0 \text{, by Itô's first isometry}$$

$$\sigma^2=\mathbb{E}[(\int_0^t W_s^2 \, dW_s)^2]-\mu^2=\int_0^t \mathbb{E}[W_s^4] \, ds-0=\int_0^t 3s^2 ds = t^3 $$
by the second isometry

Thus $$\int_0^t W_s^2 \, dW_s \sim \mathcal{N}(0,t^3)$$

Comment: It should be $\int_0^t \mathbb{E}[W_s^4] \, ds$ instead of $\int_0^t \mathbb{E}[W_s^4]\, dW_s$.

Comment: thanks, I've edited the answer

Comment: Could you please explain why $\mu$ is equal to 0? I recalculated twice and i get $\frac{t^{2}}{2}$

Comment: how are you trying to compute it?

Comment: By definition of Ito's integral, $$\int_0^t X_s \, dW_s = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_{t_i}-X_{t_{i-1}})(W_{t_i}-W_{t_{i-1}})$$
and
$$(W_{t_i}-W_{t_{i-1}}) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,t_i-t_{i-1})$$